# im new in kotlin , reset button doesnt work when i change app into dark mode but when i start count and click on it again it work

Tags: android, kotlin

```
 private lateinit var countertxt: TextView
    private lateinit var buttonclick: Button
    private lateinit var resetbutton: Button
    private var num = 0
    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        countertxt = findViewById(R.id.countertxt)
        buttonclick = findViewById(R.id.buttonclick)
        resetbutton = findViewById(R.id.resetbtn)


        buttonclick.setOnClickListener {
            num++

            countertxt.text = num.toString()


            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound)
            mediaPlayer.start()

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
                buttonclick.isEnabled = true
                mediaPlayer.release()


            }
            resetbutton.setOnClickListener {

                num = 0
                countertxt.text = num.toString()

                val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound)
                mediaPlayer.start()

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
                    buttonclick.isEnabled = true
                    mediaPlayer.release()
                }

            }
        }
    }
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        val countertxt :Int = num

        outState.putInt("SavedInt",num)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

        val userInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("SavedInt",0)
        num = userInt
        countertxt.text = num.toString()
    }
}
```

i want to know what is the code that make reset button reset to 0 correctly i think the problem in my code can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating and adding your reset button’s click listener **inside** the other button’s click listener, so the reset button won’t do anything until the other button has been clicked at least once since the last time the screen (activity or fragment) reloaded.

You need to move a closing brace `}` from after your reset button’s click listener to before before the `resetbutton.setOnClickListener {` line.

Comment: oo hahaha yeah its true thanks man ! i have another question if u can help i want when someone click reset button it reset to " start counting " then when someone start click " count " it start from 1 + how can i change it like that if u can help me please

Comment: Not clear enough explanation for me to understand what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonclick.setOnClickListener {
    num++

    countertxt.text = num.toString()
    val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound)
    mediaPlayer.start()

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
        buttonclick.isEnabled = true
        mediaPlayer.release()
    }
}
resetbutton.setOnClickListener {

    num = 0
    countertxt.text = num.toString()

    val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound)
    mediaPlayer.start()

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
        buttonclick.isEnabled = true
        mediaPlayer.release()
    }
}
```

You are creating the button click listener inside a button click listener. You need to move the `}` bracket before reset button and after doing this change it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already fixed this problem, but another thing is, you are creating:

```
val countertxt :Int = num
```

in `onSaveInstanceState` overriding function and then not using it, remove it or use it.